# Is there a continuous 1-1 function from a compact Hausdorff space X onto a compact Hausdorff space Y?

Tags: general-topology

**Let f be a one-to-one function from a compact Hausdorff space X onto a compact Hausdorff space Y. Show that if f[K] is compact for every compact K subset of X, then f is continuous.**

I know that f restricted to K must be continuous, because the continuous image of a compact set is compact. I'm not sure how to prove that f is continuous, other than the fact that every b in Y has a distinct f(b) in X because f is one-to-one and onto.

I'm not sure how to set this problem up.

Comment: "I know that f restricted to K must be continuous, because the continuous image of a compact set is compact."  You're mixing up your implication; consider any surjective map from [0,1] to {0,1}.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: show that $f$ is a closed map.  Then $f^{-1}$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact when $K$ is.  Use this to show that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I know that every compact space is closed. So each K is closed in X and is mapped to f[K], which is closed in Y (because f is one-to-one and onto each f[K] is distinct). This shows that f is a closed map? Am I missing anything?

Comment: @user114634: To show $f$ is a closed map, you have to start with an _arbitrary_ closed subset $A\subseteq X$ and show that $f(A)$ is closed in $Y$.

Comment: Well, If I take an arbitrary closed subset A of X. Then A is compact because closed subsets of compact spaces are compact. Thus, every closed space in X is compact and since f is one-to-one and surjective, there exists an f[A] in Y such that f[A] is compact (by our assumption). Thus, f is a closed map.

Comment: Not sure how to prove that f is continuous...

Comment: @user114634 A map is continuous iff the inverse image of every closed set is closed.  Since $f$ is a bijective closed map, $f^{-1}$ is continuous.  Now use the fact that continuous maps preserve compact sets ($f^{-1}$ in particular) to show that $f$ is also a closed map.

Comment: Did you mean that you are trying to show that f−1 is also a closed map?

Comment: @user114634 Yes, that's how you can do it in this case.